# How to set Guake as preferred terminal emulator for "Run in Terminal"?

Tags: command-line, preferences, guake

I've recently installed Guake and like it a lot. I'd like to set it as my preferred terminal application. That is, when I right-click on a bash script file, click "Open", and choose "Run in Terminal", I want it to open in a new Guake tab.

I'm not sure where to set Guake as the preferred app for "Run in Terminal". And I'm guessing that I might need the command to be something like `guake --new-tab=new --execute-command="COMMANDHERE"`, so how do I pass that parameter?

Ideally, I'd like a terminal invocation to open a new Guake tab, *unless* there is already one available. (Difficult to tell, what id there's already a command running in the existing tab?) Failing that, just opening a new Guake tab is ok. Also, is there an option to keep Guake hidden when this happens?

**Already tried:**

Based on [How can I set default terminal used in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70540/how-can-i-set-default-terminal-used) I have already tried:

- `gconftool --type string --set /desktop/gnome/applications/terminal/exec guake` - this made Guake appear when I type Ctrl-Alt-T.
- setting `x-terminal-emulator` to `\usr\bin\guake` in Alternatives Configurator - this made no difference (having already made the previous change).

Comment: Hey d3vid, does this solution not help your set your default terminal? http://askubuntu.com/questions/70540/how-can-i-set-default-terminal-used

Comment: @BrunePereira thanks! that's given me partial success, but also highlighted that maybe I'm not asking for the right thing, so I've clarified my question

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered. If you solved it, please post an answer explaining how it was solved (answering your own questions is not merely permitted, but [encouraged when there is no other answer that does the job](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)). If the question no longer applies you may voluntarily delete/close it.

Comment: @EricCarvalho unfortunately still not solved - I'll see if I can contact Guake users/mailing list directly and post any response here as an answer

Answer (score 7):

You could probably enjoy running `gconf-editor` — or maybe even `dconf-editor` since 12.04, — and navigate directly to the `org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal` key:

[image: dconf screenshot]

The `exec-arg` parameter must be changed to Guake's `-e`. For the lazy:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec 'guake --new-tab'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec-arg '-e'
```

Comment: adding `guake` allows me to open/display guake when I click on `Open terminal here` in nemo. But I'm still looking for a solution to open/display guake with a new tab with the correct location.

Comment: doesn't work. alt+ctrl+t still opens xfce-terminal for me

Comment: @Blauhirn let me guess, org.__gnome__.desktop.default-applications.terminal setting isn't used by XFCE? Perhaps XFCE has it's own key.