# How can I set default terminal used in Unity?

Tags: unity, command-line, shortcut-keys

How can I set the default terminal used in Unity?

I would like to use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> hotkey to start a non-default terminal. The default terminal is gnome-terminal.

Where can I change the default terminal value?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

### For 12.04 and newer

`gconf` is now deprecated - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GConf - and `gsettings` can be used in its place.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec 'terminal'
```

Where *terminal* is the command you would use to open it from the terminal.

Comment: I have installed terminator as terminal and uninstalled gnome-terminal but the command you suggested does not work for me.

Comment: Works fine for me on 13.10.

Comment: I use Terminator as my main terminal, but after running this command, ctrl+alt+T does not work anymore at all.

Comment: @user1880405 Do you have `konsole` installed?

Comment: @becko No, I don't think so.

Comment: You have to run the above command with `konsole` replaced with a terminal that you have installed on your system.

Comment: For the sake of completeness (and because I messed up) -- how do I restore the default value after using this?

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun replace `konsole` with  `gnome-terminal`

Comment: Great answer.  Works well with Gnome Desktop 14.04 too!  :)

Comment: Still works for Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: For some reason this didn't work on 16.04. Ctrl+Alt+T then had no effect. I then tried to change it back to gnome-terminal, but same thing. [@iegik's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/124718/289003) worked and Ctrl+Alt+T worked again.

Comment: Also, `dconf` or `dconf-editor` can be used as a GUI-based config tool (at least on Ubuntu 16.10).

Comment: This and the `sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator` appear to work with changing what ctrl-alt-t do, but it doesn't appear to change nautilus from opening gnome-terminal for me on ubuntu 16.04

Comment: On Ubuntu Unity 22.04, this will affect the Ctrl-Alt-T shortcut but not the "Open in terminal" option in Nemo file manager. Thanks

Answer (score 73):

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

Comment: While this is a great answer to the question (and generally a preferrable way to change a default program IMHO) this may not be the 'weapon of choice' in all circumstances. To elaborate: I wanted to set guake terminal as default but it never showed when trying to do so by *update-alternatives*.

Comment: Also, You can edit directly to the script xdg-open :)

    `sudo gedit \`which xdg-open\``

Comment: This does not change the shortcut command result, as clearly stated in the question, I don't get why it has so many upvotes.

Comment: It works for me on Ubuntu 17.04. I installed `terminology` and it became the Ctrl+Alt+T terminal. Ran `update-alternatives` and changed it back to `gnome-terminal`, and it worked immediately.

Answer (score 40):

**Only in Ubuntu 11.10 or earlier! For newer versions see [LucaB](https://askubuntu.com/a/256695/19076) answer!**

Open a terminal (e.g. gnome-terminal)

Run the next command:

```
gconftool --type string --set /desktop/gnome/applications/terminal/exec <YOUR-TERMINAL>
```

e.g.:

```
gconftool --type string --set /desktop/gnome/applications/terminal/exec terminator
```

Done :).

Comment: This doesn't fix it for me. When I start Htop via its .desktop file (which specifies `Terminal=True`), it starts in Gnome Terminal no matter what. Is there yet another place to change the default terminal emulator?

Comment: THE CORRECT ANSWER IS BELLOW!

Comment: @gerep My answer is correct, because the question defined exactly the Ubuntu version: **11.10**. Of course in the newer versions the gconftool is deprecated, so not this the right solution.

Answer (score 28):

To change the shortcut and not default termainal,

1. search for keyboard
2. go to shortcuts and custom shortcuts
3. press the plus sign to add new shortcut (in this case terminator)
4. when told that the shortcut ctrl+alt+t is already in use press "reasign"

[image: search for keyboard]
[image: add new shortcut]
[image: reasign]

Comment: does not work for me.

Comment: +100 for being the easiest to understand and the one that has withstood the test of time.

Comment: Since `sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator` came back with "There is only one alternative in link group x-terminal-emulator (providing /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator): /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper
Nothing to configure." and this even though I have Guake installed, I used this option. Changed the normal terminal to Shift+Ctrl+Alt+T and setup Guake to use Ctrl+Alt+T in its place. The only issue is that I'd like to right click and Open in Terminal too. Plus, Guake is set to F12 and what I prefer to use over Ctrl+Alt+T either way. It's a nice addition, nonetheless.

Answer (score 7):

Try to change option `x-terminal-emulator` via "ALternatives Configurator" app.

for ubuntu you can use the command below:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

It will list all the terminal options you have installed and then you can pick (by the number) the one you want.

Comment: a little bit helping: 'Alternatives Configurator' is 'galternatives'

Answer (score 5):

To configure the default terminal in gnome you need to install `dconf-tools` (`sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`).

After that you can use the `gsettings` to set your favorite terminal emulator.

Lets say your favourite terminal emulator is `termite`.

Install it with `sudo apt-get install termite`

After that type this command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec termite
```

Since `termite` does not take any arguments (or it does, depends on what you do with it, you can set them this way) use this to set empty or set the exec-args for the terminal you need

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec-arg ""
```

After this `termite` will be your default terminal emulator.

Comment: there is another way outlined in http://askubuntu.com/questions/70540/how-can-i-set-default-terminal-used

Comment: Its the same thing, really does not mater, this way uses the replacement tool for `gconf`

Comment: exec-arg didn't work for me unfortunately. I was trying to start terminal in fullscreen mode. The only option that helped was specifying the option in configuration. I am using terminator

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

Comment: Hmm, on second thought, this doesn't seem to be updating it.

Answer (score 2):

The update-alternatives system is a Debian thing, but Gnome run on many more distributions, so it has its own way to define preferred applications.

You can set default terminal through the utility `gnome-default-applications-properties`, also accessible through `gnome-control-center` as *Preferred Applications*.

Alternatively you can set the gconf registry key `/desktop/gnome/applications/terminal/exec`.

However, it is not guaranteed that all applications provided by Gnome, like nautilus, will respect this setting, or rather use their own settings.

Answer (score 2):

This worked in Ubuntu 13.10

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec terminator
```

Comment: This is what worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04 with terminator

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the Keyboard shortcuts, you will notice under the Launcher section that Ctrl+Alt+T is tied to the "Launch Terminal" action. I haven't tested it yet, but you can create a Custom Shortcut to your preferred Terminal, and bind that shortcut to it instead.

Answer (score 0):

OK, one weird thing is that the compiled `gnome-terminal` with the patch will not work if your DISPLAY var is :0 , works flawlessly if DISPLAY=localhost:0.

So you can edit `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal/wrapper` and add this:

```
ENV{"DISPLAY"}="localhost:0";
```

right before the exec line.

Subsequently you can use `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal/wrapper` as the launcher!

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo update-alternatives --set x-terminal-emulator <terminal-path>
```

For example:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set x-terminal-emulator /usr/bin/tilix
```

If you want to do it with interactive mode or check paths:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```