# How to open a terminal from the terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal

I'm on ubuntu 12.04 and I use gnome terminal as my default terminal. I need to open another terminal from the command line. I know I can do this with  gnome-terminal but I want to run a command that always opens the default terminal so that my script can run on other distros, even the ones not using gnome.

EDIT: I want a bash script that opens the terminal.

Comment: Please clarify your question with specifics. What type of script you are executing and on which shell (terminal) you want to run the scripts? Give us a usecase, like my shell script is this and I want to run it in `csh` or `zsh` or `bash`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`xterm` is available by default on almost all Linux distributions if I remember correctly.

So you could run a command in it, depending on the shell that the script's written in with something like this, (the example is for a bash shell script)

```
xterm -e "sh script.sh"
```

It'll spawn a new shell window and execute your script.

Comment: Just to know there isn't a system variable or something like that that calls the default terminal on the system?

Comment: `echo $TERM` tells you the name, whereas `$TERM` launches it. Most of the time it's `xterm` :)

Answer (score 2):

According to the answer to this question [How can I set default terminal used in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70540/how-can-i-set-default-terminal-used-in-unity) I would script it as follows:

```
 eval "$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec)"
```

If you would like to start a program inside the terminal, there is also the property 'exec-arg' which specifies the argument needed to execute something in the terminal by that specific terminal. For example when you want to execute a 'tail -f /var/log/messages':

```
CMD='tail -f /var/log/messages'
eval "$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec) $(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec exec-arg) \$CMD"
```

The 'eval' is used because 'gsettings' returns the command and the argument in single-quotes.
This would then be a generic solution for all desktops running GNOME/Unity.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use either this key combination `CTRL + SHIFT + T` which opens another tab in the same terminal window, or you might want to use this one: `CTRL + ALT + T` which opens another terminal window (without closing the one you currently use.).