# why doesn't the standardized way to change default terminal work?

Tags: default, terminator, update-alternatives

Why doesn't: `sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator`
Work to change the default terminal in 12.10 ubuntu-one nautilus? I find it
confusing.

Comment: what do you mean with "cannot change"? You mean shortcut wise (as in ctrl+alt+t)?

Answer (score 1):

Since Ubuntu 12.04 there is a new tool to change default applications. According to this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/256695/59054), we need to use `gsettings` now. I can confirm that it works on Ubuntu 13.10.

For example, if you want to use Sakura as default terminal:

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec 'sakura'`

Comment: You should include the essential parts of your answer here and provide the link for reference, as link only answers may become invalid if the link is lost (something like that)