# Installing Terminator changes default terminal. How to set it back to GNOME terminal?

Tags: command-line

I installed `terminator` and it changed my default terminal. I want to reset it to GNOME terminal. How can I do it?

Comment: same as this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/70540/how-can-i-set-default-terminal-used-in-unity?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

The default terminal is defined by the environment variable called TERM. You need to change it and save the following command in your .profile if you want to have xterm as your default terminal for instance:

```
export TERM="xterm"
```