# How to make "open in terminal" in the right click menu use Terminator instead of gnome terminal?

Tags: unity, default-programs, terminator

I have set the default terminal emulator to terminator using `update-alternatives` and I can open terminator now with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>t</kbd>, but when I use the right click menu on the desktop or in a folder it will open gnome-terminal.

Is there another setting to change to fix this?

I've edited compiz to try the 3d cube effect and from then had to reset compiz to default settings to revert which reset my terminal default. To get <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>t</kbd> working after this I also had to do `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec 'terminator'`. I found this suggestion in 
[How can I set default terminal used in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70540/how-can-i-set-default-terminal-used-in-unity/256695#256695), but this did not make it so the right click option open terminator.

I am using Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: The problem is that it's not supposed to be changed: the entry is "Open in Terminal" (mind the uppercase "T"). It's supposed to open Terminal, which is the Unity .desktop front-end to `gnome-terminal`, not a generic terminal. Nonetheless it would be indeed nice to have options.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The settings in `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec` doesn't affect the behavior of the context menu entry. The used terminal is `gnome-terminal` and that's *hard coded* in `libterminal-nautilus.so` in the package `gnome-terminal`. And this library is used by Nautilus.

Perhaps this will be changed in future versions, but currently it is a fact.

Comment: This is why [some people](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/usability/2005-December/msg00022.html) rather strongly dislike the GNOME project.  "We know better than our users" indeed.

Comment: The relevant bug is https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=627943. Mostly the developers answers are the one outlined by @Kevin... The only solution now is using a workaround like the one suggested here in http://askubuntu.com/a/692785/16395

Comment: I even proposed a patch... https://bug743626.bugzilla-attachments.gnome.org/attachment.cgi?id=295624

Comment: This issue is not fixed yet https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/-/issues/338
But they did a workaround which will be available in the next reelease https://gitlab.gnome.org/VannTen/glib/-/commit/17af5d0ae9bbad3634bb9a4b3a8a783788b65f4e

Answer (score 9):

A solution that might work is to add a custom right-click option to the Ubuntu context menu entry instead of changing the pre-existing one.

For that purpose you can use the Nautilus-Actions Configuration Tool that you can get from the repository using `sudo apt-get install nautilus-actions`.

A quite well detailed tutorial can be found [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/116807/how-to-easily-add-custom-right-click-options-to-ubuntus-file-manager/).

Comment: I liked this answer but it did not say what to put into that nautilus action, I found it out though: `terminator` into `Path` and `--working-directory=%d/%b` into `Parameters` then as it says later in the tutorial: "click the Preferences button in the Nautilus-Actions Configuration Tool window and uncheck the “Create a root ‘Nautilus-Actions’ menu” option"

Answer (score 6):

Add this to your ~/.bashrc file

```
if ps -o cmd= -p $(ps -o ppid= -p $$) | grep -q gnome; then
  nohup terminator &> /dev/null &
  sleep 0.1s
  exit
fi
```

Comment: How would this solve OP's problem? Also, wouldn't this cause other possible weirdnesses in theory?

Comment: This will check if the current terminal is gnome-terminal and then open a terminator session from gnome-terminal and then close the gnome-terminal.  nothing here causes weirdnesses.

Comment: Wow. That's what I call lateral thinking. If mildly insane in principle, this works flawlessly in practice (on 17.04).

Comment: It's an okay solution

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use `gnome-terminal` on a regular basis, and you don't mind the possibility of having your hack disturbed by package upgrades, and other occasional problems, you could try removing `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal` (or renaming it) and replacing it with a symlink to `terminator`.

A slightly less intrusive approach, that would work if the context menu respects `PATH`, would be to leave `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal` alone, but add a symlink from `/usr/local/bin/gnome-terminal` to `/usr/bin/terminator`, so that anything running `gnome-terminal` without a fully-qualified path actually gets terminator.