# Is there a way to launch Terminator when right clicking "Open in Terminal" for Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-terminal, terminator

Currently when I right click on a directory and select **Open in Terminal** the default is still GNOME terminal. I have Terminator installed. Is there a way to make it default instead?

I have read [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/692599/how-to-make-open-in-terminal-in-the-right-click-menu-use-terminator-instead-gn/692620), and wonder if the situation has been improved?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't show in default applications settings so set it from the command line:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

Comment: How can I add Yakuake to that list?