# How can I set the default terminal? Preferably from the command line

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

How can I set the default terminal emulator? Preferably from the command line.

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.03, and Unity and Lubuntu desktops

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

Should run something like:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator

There are 7 alternatives which provide `x-terminal-emulator’.

Selection Alternative
———————————————–
    1 /usr/bin/xterm
    2 /usr/bin/uxterm
    3 /usr/bin/koi8rxterm
    4 /usr/bin/lxterm
*+ 5 /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper
    6 /usr/bin/konsole
    7 /usr/bin/xfce4-terminal.wrapper

Press enter to keep the default[*], or type selection number:
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

recommended [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/72519/455406), [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/124718/455406), and [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/set-the-default-terminal-emulator-on-ubuntu-linux/) seems to work.

Comment: ur answer is essentially a referral to another question, it would be better to flag this question as a duplicate of the other (with the [flag] button below this one).