# making go terminal default terminal

Tags: 16.04, shortcut-keys

How do I make Go Terminal default terminal instead of Ubuntu's original terminal?

Also changing all shortcuts to open Go Terminal(ctrl+alt+T)

Comment: Which desktop environment are you using? Unity? Gnome?

Comment: @AndreaBorga I am using default 16.04 i.e. Unity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From similar post...](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70540/how-can-i-set-default-terminal-used-in-unity)

**For 12.04 and newer**

> gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec 'goterminal'